# gawk windows pathname (directory) expansion (glob)

Tags: windows, awk, glob, gawk

In gawk for Windows version 3.1.6, it doesn't expand directory names on the command line.  I try something like:

```
gawk -f simple.awk */*.cpp
```

where simple.awk is

```
{ print FILENAME; }
```

and gawk complains that it `cannot open */*.cpp`. It works if I cd to a directory and run:

```
gawk -f simple.awk *.cpp
```

Is there an easy way to expand/glob the directories, passing in `*/*.cpp`?

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an awk problem, but a Windows command line problem. It doesn't support wildcards/globs.

Check this thread about it and the possible suggested solutions:

https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths

Comment: Thanks. Later Windows versions of  gawk, though, will take the string `*/*.cpp` as an argument and do the expansion itself.

Comment: Try with gawk 4.1.4 from ezwinports at sourceforge.

Comment: that did it. Thanks.

Comment: @MJF – on this site, please mark most useful answer with check mark

Comment: @miroxlav I will do, but the current response is only mildly useful. Yes, Windows doesn't support those wildcards, but awk (or perhaps gawk) *does*. Other comments (such as that from @valrog) have pointed me to the solution.